# How do I tune symbol column capacity in QuestDB?

Tags: database, questdb

Say, I have a symbol column with 1M unique values and 10M rows per day and I want to add an index for that column.

How do I tune symbol and index capacity to make sure that QuestDB performance is optimal?

The default values are 256:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (symb SYMBOL CAPACITY 256 INDEX CAPACITY 256);
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally symbols use a symbol table, i.e. a mapping from string values to internal ids (32-bit integers).

There are two separate capacity settings:

1. Symbol table capacity: `symb SYMBOL CAPACITY N` - this one should be at least as big as the expected number of unique symbol values. You could think of the symbol table as a persistent hash table: if the number of buckets is insufficient, there will be unnecessary bucket scans on lookups.
2. Index block capacity: `symb SYMBOL INDEX CAPACITY M` - we recommend keeping the default value for this one which is 256. Index blocks are part of a persistent linked list that stores row ids for a given symbol value. There is no need to tweak this capacity as the linked list grows when needed.

You should set the symbol table capacity as big as the expected number of unique symbol values while keeping the default value for the index block capacity:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (symb SYMBOL CAPACITY 1000000 INDEX);
```

There is also `CACHE`/`NOCACHE` setting which either enables or disables on-heap cache used for symbol lookups. It's enabled by default and we recommend disabling it only when your symbol column has a lot of unique values (way more than a million) or you have many symbol columns, so that JVM heap won't fit caches for all of them.

One more thing to notice: while indexes help to avoid full scans in certain queries, they slow down inserts. We recommend starting with no index and then adding them if you find the query performance insufficient.

Comment: Are you mean Symbol table is a hash table, so small capacity means greater likelihood of conflict, but still works. If I want to record the time series data of my users, and the number of my users may grow, so I don't know how many my users will be. What symbol capacity should I set?

Comment: "so small capacity means greater likelihood of conflict, but still works":

Yes, that's correct.

"What symbol capacity should I set?":

You may set the capacity to a 5x-10x value of what you expect in terms of the number of users.

Comment: What are the disadvantages of excessively large symbol capacity? Start with a small symbol capacity. Can I make it bigger in the future?

Comment: There are no disadvantages except for the disk overhead. As for changing the capacity, you'd have to recreate the column to do that (see https://questdb.io/docs/troubleshooting/faq/#how-do-i-convert-a-string-column-to-a-symbol-or-vice-versa for the instructions on how to do that).

Comment: What is the relationship between disk load and symbol capacity? If the symbol capacity is set to millions, or even tens of millions, will a huge amount of disk space be wasted? Disks from cloud providers are not free, after all. I know the hash table is an array with fixed capacity size. So perhaps too big symbol capacity will consume all my disk?

Comment: As a rough estimate, you may assume the disk overhead is 16 bytes * symbol_capacity. So, symbol capacity set to 1M would require 16M to store the internal symbol table.

Comment: It seems that it is not very large. So the disk size occupied by the symbol table is only related to the symbol capacity, and has nothing to do with the total amount of data？

Comment: That's right. You could say that it has to do with the total number of distinct symbol values, not with the total number of rows in the table.